# RFC FORMAT 2822 Copy and BCC emails can't see the original message when I reply, they can only see the reply, how can I make them see the original msg

Tags: email, postman, gmail-api, rfc, rfc2822

I am trying to reply an email on the original message ID through the gmail API by converting the request body message in RFC 2822 format to base64, the original sender can see the reply along with the original message, but when I copy it to other emails, they can only see the reply, what do I need to do for the copy emails to see the replies along with the original message? Below is email in RFC 2822 format that I am converting to base64:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=foo_bar_baz
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: mail1@domain.com.br
To: original@domain.com.br
Cc: copymail@domain.com.br
Subject: Re: Test
In-Reply-To: <Message id of original@domain.com.br mail>
References: <Message id of original@domain.com.br mail>

--foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

Hello!

--foo_bar_baz--
```

I tried various things like putting the copy's email in the "To: " header and nothing happened. Only the original email gets to see the reply along with the original message itself.